# lxterminal show tool bar

Tags: raspbian-wheezy, lxterminal

In Lxterminal I chose the option under "Display" to hide the toolbar, thinking that pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> would make it pop up again. It doesn't. Without the toolbar, I can't see/access the toolbar.

Is there a command to bring it back? The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/lxterminal.1.html) was not helpful to me.

Comment: Ah no! Right mouse button does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `nano ~/.config/lxterminal/lxterminal.conf`, and change this line:

```
hidemenubar=true
```

to:

```
hidemenubar=false
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit. Then exit LXTerminal if that is what you are currently using.

This works even in LXTerminal

Another way would be to right click and click 'Preferences', and untick 'Hide menu bar' under the 'Display' tab.